# Using xPath to get price (using greater than)

Tags: php, regex, xpath

How could I use the following xPath example:

```
//book[price>35.00]
```

With this (since the dollar sign is static):

```
<div class="book"><span class="price">$35</span></div>
```

**------------------
Edited from answer
------------------**

```
    $vu_link = get_field('vu_link');

    $ch3 = curl_init($vu_link);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $cl3 = curl_exec($ch3);

    $dom3 = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom3->loadHTML($cl3);
    $xpath3 = new DOMXpath($dom3);

    $price3 = $xpath3->query("//div[@class = 'price-box' and substring(span[@class = 'price'], 2) > 100]");

    foreach ($xpath->query($price3) as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Use string and numeric functions from xpath. See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp , something like number and substring in your condition should solve your problem ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an xpath expression along the lines of:

`//div[@class = 'book' and substring(span[@class = 'price'], 2) > 35]`

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
<div class="book"><span class="price">$35</span></div>
<div class="book"><span class="price">$34</span></div>
<div class="book"><span class="price">$33</span></div>
<div class="book"><span class="price">$36</span></div>
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = "//div[@class = 'book' and substring(span[@class = 'price'], 2) > 35]";

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<div class="book"><span class="price">$36</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. However, I'm battling a bit to implement it:/ I've updated my original question - am I on the right track?

Comment: Ok sure, I'll do that. Thanks so much for the pointer Paul. I'll try my hand at trying to figure it out again, and then post a new question if I'm still stuck later this week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the given xpath

```html
/div[@class="book"]/span[@class="price"]/text()
```